# Read byte[] from json using System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-webapi, system.text.json

I receive dynamic JSON in my web api post request.

```
[HttpPost("receive")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ReceiveJson([FromBody] JsonDocument document)
```

One of my JSON elements is a binary array:

```
"attachments": [
    {
        "content": [
            255,
            216,                
            ...
            128,
            70
        ]
    }
```

I am unable to read that array into anything really.
I can get it as a JsonElement and see that it is ValueKind Array:

```
ok = attachment.TryGetProperty("content", out JsonElement attachmentContent);
string attachmentContentType = attachmentContent.ValueKind.ToString();
//gives Array
```

But how do I get it itto a byte[]?

Comment: Where exactly do you stuck? You have a `JsonElement` which have methods like `EnumerateArray()` and even an indexer [`Item[32]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement.item?view=net-8.0#system-text-json-jsonelement-item(system-int32)) to get the entries of your array.

Comment: You could deserialize using the `JsonConverter<byte []>` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76264120/3744182) to [C# Parse `byte[]` to json without converting to base64 string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76263968/3744182).  Does that answer your question?  Or just do `attachmentContent.EnumerateArray().Select(e => e.GetByte()).ToArray()` as hinted by @Progman.

Comment: @Progman, thanks. 
I think what threw me was that there is no ToByteArray() method.
Interestingly enough there is [GetBytesFromBase64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement.getbytesfrombase64?view=net-8.0)
I did the same as Gowthaman in the his answer but this had me wondering if I was going down the wrong path.
Would there be amethond that retrieves it as base64 without manually looping it as well?

Answer (score 0):

The following code is a custom JSON converter for byte array:

```
public class JsonByteArrayConverter : JsonConverter<byte[]>
{
    public override byte[] Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartArray)
        {
            throw new JsonException();
        }

        var byteArray = new List<byte>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndArray)
            {
                return byteArray.ToArray();
            }

            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.Number)
            {
                byteArray.Add(reader.GetByte());
            }
        }

        throw new JsonException();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, byte[] value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

As an example:

```
string jsonString = "{\"attachments\":[{\"content\":[255,216,12,70]}]}";

// Deserialize the JSON string
var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonString);

// Access the binary array and convert it to a byte array
byte[] byteArray = deserializedObject.attachments[0].content.ToObject<byte[]>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code retrieves byte[] from the JsonElement:

```
int count;
List<byte> contentValues = new List<byte>();

using (JsonDocument document = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonString))
{
    JsonElement root = document.RootElement;
    JsonElement attachmentsElement = root.GetProperty("attachments");

    count = attachmentsElement.GetArrayLength();

    foreach (JsonElement student in attachmentsElement.EnumerateArray())
    {
        if (student.TryGetProperty("content", out JsonElement contentElement))
        {
            foreach(JsonElement ele in contentElement.EnumerateArray())
            {
                contentValues.Add(ele.GetByte());
            }
        }
    }
}

byte[] allContents = contentValues.ToArray();
```

Comment: I did the same but I suggest you look at the comment by Progman, the linq code
attachmentContent.EnumerateArray().Select(e => e.GetByte()).ToArray()